# Geth: bootnode tool and --nodiscover

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, node-discovery, bootnodes

In Geth, if I use the `--nodiscover` option, my node won't be discovered by default from other nodes.

Conversely, with bootnode tool implemented in geth, first I have to generate a key, then I have to use the command

```
bootnode -nodekey "./boot.key" -addr "addr:port"
```

and lastly I have to put the output enode information as parameter when starting each node (so that I can have an authomatic "adding peers mechanism"). However, using this tool, I can't use `--nodiscover` option.

Is it less secure to use this tool? Could my nodes be discovered from external nodes?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you will be if your network id and the genesis files are same on the other side of the network. I started receiving block from public ip after removing --nodiscover option

Answer (score 0):

When --nodiscover is used at the time of starting a geth node, it prevents the node to be discovered by the bootnode in the network. As a result, the geth node will not join in Ping-Pong request exchange of UDP discover protocol.

If you want your geth node to be discovered by the bootnode, make sure --nodiscover is not used
geth --datadir *datadirpath*
or in toml configuration file, NoDiscovery flag is to be set false.

So the answer of your first question is: No. It is secured as long as boot node is a trusted entity in your network.

The answer of your second question is: To make the nodes automatically connected with each other, you have to use bootnode like mentioned previously.